# How to define variable for different build types in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to install both release and debug app version on the same device. I added `applicationIdSuffix` in `buildTypes.debug`. Also I have providers in manifest. For example, `androidx.core.content.FileProvider`. It use custom `authorities` from `defaultConfig`. Because need to use it in code:

```kotlin
FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITIES, programFile)
```

The issue with `def fileProviderAuthorities`. `applicationIdSuffix` equal to empty string, not `.debug`. If I try write `def` in `buildTypes.debug` occurs error `Could not find method applicationId()`.

How to define variable in order to create string `${applicationId}${applicationIdSuffix}.fileprovider` with different value for both release and debug versions? For example, `com.example.appname` and `com.example.appname.debug`.

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${fileProviderAuthorities}"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.appname"
    applicationIdSuffix ""
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 34
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.0.0"

    def fileProviderAuthorities = "${applicationId}${applicationIdSuffix}.fileprovider"
    buildConfigField "String", "FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITIES", "\"${fileProviderAuthorities}\""

    manifestPlaceholders = [
        "fileProviderAuthorities": fileProviderAuthorities,
    ]
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        // error: Could not find method applicationId()
        // def fileProviderAuthorities = "${applicationId}${applicationIdSuffix}.fileprovider"
        // buildConfigField "String", "FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITIES", "\"${fileProviderAuthorities}\""
    }
}
```

Comment: Define constants for the various pieces, such as `.debug`, that you can reference both in the configuration (e.g., `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"`) and in the string interpolation.